# Related rate problem? Help

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know the answer. I just don't know how to get it myself. Can someone give me a hint? I know my derivative rules. I just don't know what I am taking the derivative of. If someone will help me with the first step, I will gladly do the rest myself. I put a link below of the picture, I don't know how to embed it with this post.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLvdq.png

Update 1: I was told to type the question out. So here it is:

The two blades of a pair of scissors are fastened at the point A as shown in figure below. Let a
denote the distance from A to the tip of the blade (the point B). Let β denote the angle at the tip of
the blade that is formed by the line AB and the bottom edge of the blade, line BC and let θ denote
the angle between AB and the horizontal. Suppose that a piece of paper is cut in such a way that
the center of the scissors at A is fixed, and the paper is also fixed. As the blades are closed (i.e.,
the angle θ in the diagram is decreased), the distance x between A and C increases, cutting the
paper.

Suppose that the distance a is 20 cm, and the angle β is 5
degrees.Further suppose that θ is decreasing at 50 degrees per second.
At the instant when θ=30∘, find the rate (in cm/sec) at which the
paper is being cut

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: To post the image, click on the box that includes what looks like a sun rising above the mountains.  It will then ask you to upload the image.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - posting images required a minimum reputation the OP does not yet have.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Posting text as an image is not allowed on this site as it does not allow search engines to see your questions (making the question non-reusable). Please type your question down.

Comment: @5xum So if I type it out, will you help me with the first step?

Comment: @DeanBearl If you type it out, I will read the question and attempt to answer it. More importantly, downvotes on this question will dissappear, and upvotes might appear. Even more importantly, other users on this page will also be more likely to answer it.

Comment: @5xum I am getting more downvotes and I typed it out. Why? My question is a honest question. I just didn't know what to do and was asking for the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative you are after is $\dot x = {dx \over dt}$ From the information in the question, you can find $x$ as a function of $\theta$, and you are given that $\dot \theta = {50^\circ\over\text{sec}}$. So once to you figure out $x$ in terms of $\theta$, just apply the chain rule.

To find $x$ in terms of $\theta$, remember that the angles of a triangle add up to $180^\circ$, and apply the Law of Sines.

Comment: Thanks, I hit the upvote, but its not working :(. But thank you for your help.